# Not able to access Apache Tomcat Server 9.0.73 remotely

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, tomcat-manager

I have installed Apache Tomcat 9.0.73 on RHEL remote machine.

I followed the installation steps from this link - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-on-linux

Apache Tomcat Service is running properly, but I am not able to access it remotely.
For example - http://<Remote_IP_Addr>:8080/
Tried accessing manger & host-manager profiles as well but facing the same issue.

Till now I have tried the following -

1. Allowed 8080 port
2. Bind the address to 0.0.0.0 in the server.xml
3. Added new role & user for manager-gui & admin-gui in tomcat-users.xml
4. Commented Valve tag in context.xml of manager & host-manager profiles.
   Referred ans from this link - https://serverfault.com/questions/796960/how-to-access-tomcat-manager-gui-from-another-machine

Let me know if this is the right way to access it remotely. I am facing this issue for quite some time.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What actually happens when you *do* try to access it?